# How to get the file name from a Power Automate "When a HTTP request is received" trigger action

Tags: http, power-automate, request-headers

I have a Flow with a trigger action of "When a HTTP request is received".  When I post a single file to the trigger I can save it to SharePoint, as below, with the `triggerBody()` providing the file content.

Currently I'm using a hard coded string as the file name and it works fine, but how do I get file name from the posted file?
[image: MyFlow]

Comment: Unfortunately I have no answer to this question, but I want to achieve the same thing. How did you configure "When a HTTP request is received" to upload a file? And how does the file upload call looks like, e.g. in curl? Would be great if you can help me.

Comment: Add a Parse_JSON action between the 2 actions above then you can read the filename from the JSON returned by the new action

Answer (score 0):

This issue bothers me a lot, but not being able to retrieve the filename directly from the file data value, so I have posted a separate object for the fileName

This is an old question, but the below post might be helpful for the community.
[Upload a file to SharePoint document library using Power automate Flow](https://siddiquemahsud.blogspot.com/2022/06/upload-file-to-sharepoint-document.html)

Thanks